# Disabling a row in a DOJO / Gridx grid

Tags: grid, dojo, dojo.gridx

I have a grid I created in Gridx which lists a bunch of users. Upon clicking a ROW in the grid (any part of that row), a dialog pops up and shows additional information about that user and actions that can be done for that user (disable user, ignore user, etc.) - when one of these options is selected from the pop up, I want to DISABLE that row. The logic for getting the row, etc. I can take care of, but I can't figure out how to make a grid row actually "appear" disabled and how to make that row no longer clickable.

Is there a simple way to do this? If you aren't familiar with gridx, solutions that apply to EnhancedGrids or other Dojo grids are also appreciated.

Comment: How are you reading the row clicks? Are you listening to the onRowClick event? And what do you mean by appearing disabled?

Comment: Yes, I am listening to the onRowClick event. When I say appearing disabled, I mean that it should "look" like its disabled - like its grayed out or faded like how a button looks faded you can't click it.

Answer (score 0):

Alright now that I have a little more information here is a solution:

Keep a list of all the rows you have disabled so far either inside the Grid widget or in its parent code. Then on the onRowClick listener I would write code like this:

```
on(grid, "onRowClick", function(e) {
    if(disabledRows[rowIndex]) {
        return;
    }

    // Do whatever pop up stuff you want and after
    // a user selects the value, you can "disable"
    // your row afterwards by adding it to the disabled
    // list so that it can no longer be clicked on.

    var rowIndex = e.rowIndex;
    disabledRows[rowIndex] = true;

    // This is just some random class I made up but
    // you can use css to stylize the row however you want
    var rowNode = e.rowNode;
    domClass.add(rowNode, "disabled");

});
```

Note that domClass is what I named "dojo/dom-class". Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps not exactly what you are seaching for:
If you want to hide one or more rows by your own filterfunction you could just add to these rows in the DOM your own class for nodisplay. Here I show you a function for display only those rows which have in a choiceable field/column a value inside your filterlist.

```
function hideRowFilter(gridId, fieldName, filterList)
{
    var store = gridId.store;
    var rowId;
    store.query(function(object){
        rowId = gridId.row(object.id,true).node();
        if  (filterList.indexOf(object[fieldName]) == -1)
            domClass.add(rowId, "noDisplay"); // anzeigen
        else
            domClass.remove(rowId, "noDisplay"); // verstecken
    });
}
```

CSS:

```
.noDisplay { display: none; }
```

So I can for example display only the entries with a myState of 3 or 4 with this call:

```
hideRowFilter(gridId, 'myState', [3, 4]);
```

Note that domClass is what I named "dojo/dom-class"